# Applying rotation invariant linear operators to spherical harmonics

Tags: operator-theory, spherical-harmonics

In the article "On boundary condition for multidimensional diffusion processes" A Venttsel says:

[image]

[image]

I can't see how one can "prove that any other harmonic of order $n$ may be represented as a linear combination of various rotations of $Y_n(\omega)$.